# How to sum a number of rows based on a value in a different cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to make a formula that will calculate how much of my mortgage I have paid in principal given the number of months I specify.  I have a worksheet that has my Loan Amortization Schedule, and on a second worksheet I am trying to figure out how much of the principal I have paid down in 12 months, 24 months, 47 months, etc.

I would like to know how to calculate this.  In one cell I'll enter the number of months (12, 24, 47, etc.) and then in a cell directly below it I will put the formula that will return all of the principal payments in a particular column on my Loan Amortization Schedule worksheet given whatever value I had put for the number of months (again 12, 24, 47, etc.).

Can someone plesae help?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`VLOOKUP` function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx).

Sheet1:

```
       A      B
1    Month  Value
2      1     100
3      2     200
4      3     300
5      4     400
6      5     500
```

Sheet2

```
        A         B
1     Month    4
2     Value    =VLOOKUP(B1,Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

**EDIT** following your comment, you want a sum up to that month, which could be done this way:

```
        A         B
1     Month    4
2     Value    =SUMIF(Sheet1!A:A,"<="&B1,Sheet1!B:B)
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for answering my question @assylias.  I think that is half way there!  I was able to get the VLOOKUP function to work, but it only returns the principal payment in that particular row.  How do I now sum up that row, plus all the other rows (i.e. months) before it?

Answer (score 0):

This will calculate the amount of principle paid on a $160k mortgage at 5% on a 15 year amortization up to the month in cell H7

```
=CUMPRINC(0.05/12,15*12,160000,1,H7,0)
```